# How does $\frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}$ convert into $- i \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

A proof I am studying showed the following step:

$\dfrac{1}{i} \cdot \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} + \dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} = \dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} - i \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}$

I do not understand how $\dfrac{1}{i} \cdot \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}$ converts into $- i \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}$.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can please take the time to show me the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Because $1/i = -i$.

Comment: @JackyChong Can you please prove to me that this is true?

Comment: @ThePointer How do you define $\,i\,$? If it's $\,i^2=-1\,$ then just divide both sides by $\,i\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I understand now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because
$$\frac{1}{i}=-i$$
Proof:
$$\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{i}\times\frac{-i}{-i}=\frac{1\times (-i)}{i\times (-i)}=\frac{-i}{-i^2}=\frac{-i}{1}=-i$$

Comment: Very illuminating! Thank you very much for the assistance. I will accept your answer when the timer allows.